# How to trim length of a "Speaker" clip in the NLA editor?

Tags: nla-editor

On trying to sync the "Speaker" Sound clip to an Action animation (NLA editor), there doesn't seem to be a way to trim longer clips in the soundtrack.

Although there is a *StripExtents* option, it doesn't affect the actual sound and the sound plays way beyond the stripextents.

Also, the option to **mute** the speaker is not animatable.

Other than importing individual sound clips in the VSE (which defeats the purpose of using the speaker), is there a way to trim the sound clip directly in the NLA editor?

[image]

Comment: Good question. The standard way is to press Y to split the strip. This works on regular action strips, but not on speaker strips. I don't know why.